# What is "Dispatching Threads"

Tags: java

Well, I am not an native speaker so sometimes I am having difficulties when I read something about programming and this time is something like that :

I am consistently seeing "... dispatching threads" and I am wondering whether it means "running a thread" or "stopping or quitting thread" in Android documents.

And also what does it mean generally in programming.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean:  *native **english** speaker* ?

Comment: Yes, I mean *native english speaker* but it is called *native speaker* almost always here in America lol :)

Comment: I must be in the wrong America because I've never heard that expression, though I presumed you meant native English and not native machine.

Comment: I don't know, because I always hear they say that. That's weird tho :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatching means to start a thread. Think of it like an emergency operator **dispatches** emergency personnel to the scene of an accident, i.e., he/she tells them where to go and **starts** them on their way.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are referring to the "Event Dispatch Thread" or EDT.

From http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=1263:

> All UI operations are performed in a
>   single thread in the native Linux
>   process. This is pretty much the way
>   all graphics on desktop and mobile
>   platforms are performed. This single
>   thread of execution is called the EDT,
>   and it is spawned by the OS when you
>   have a graphical app (as opposed to a
>   command line app or an entirely non
>   visual one). All UI operations,
>   paints, updates, etc. are done on this
>   thread, and it is important to keep
>   long running, high latency tasks off
>   of this thread of execution

Comment: Without a quote of the text the OP is referring to, it is hard to tell. Understanding what an Event Dispatch Thread is will likely be paramount to programming in Android, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

I understand it as: *"The thread that makes the task run".*

Answer (score 2):

I can see how that would be slightly confusing terminology.

In this case, the meaning of *dispatch* is "the act of sending off something" - you dispatch a thread to carry out a task, like you would dispatch a messenger to carry a package.